# Map листов перевести в list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Имеется

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>
```

как его можно перевести в Java 8 в

```
List<Integer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = ...

List<Integer> list = map.values()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```